# Library Mozart does not exist in SAS

Tags: sas

I have written the following to store a file:

```
libname mozart 'C:\Users\PCPCPC\Documents\sasdeposite\learning';

data mozart.test_scores;
length ID $ 3 Name $ 15;
input ID $ Score1-Score3 Name $;
datalines;
1 90 95 98
2 78 77 75
3 88 91 92
;
```

But the compiler says that the library MOZART does not exist. But I can see MOZART in Solution->Analysis->Interactive dataAnalysis.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that folder location exists on the computer.

SAS will not create the folder for you if it doesn't already exist.